# rosjava = pure java ros master?

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm testing rosjava (last version I hope), from this instruction :
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

But I don't understand a basis : is it not possible to run a pure java ros master (ros core ?).

In all the tutorial it is ask to run the "standard" roscore (C++/python).

By advance thank you for helping me to understand rosjava.

Regards,

Gaëtan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34417/rosjava-=-pure-java-ros-master-?/) by [Gaëtan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1463/ga%C3%ABtan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava_core is a pure ros_core java implementation.

You either run the python standard roscore or rosjava_core as the main ros process (not both).

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2